# How to use the $filter variable on graphql query under the Connect component?

Tags: react-native, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I have a simple query auto-generated from aws AppSync, and I'm trying to use the Connect Component, with a FlatList and use a TextInput to filter and auto-update the list. But I confess I didn't found out a way to do that... any hints?

Tried to find more information about this without success...

Auto-Generated query:

```
export const listFood = `query ListFood(
  $filter: ModelFoodFilterInput
  $limit: Int
  $nextToken: String
) {
  listFood(filter: $filter, limit: $limit, nextToken: $nextToken) {
    items {
      id
      name
      description
...
```

My current code, which I don't quite know where to place my filter value:

```
            <Connect query={graphqlOperation(queries.listFood)}>
                {
                    ( { data: { listFood }, loading, error } ) => {

                        if(error) return (<Text>Error</Text>);

                        if(loading || !listFood) return (<ActivityIndicator />);

                        return (
                            <FlatList
                                data={listFood.items}
                                renderItem={({item}) => {
                                    return (
                                        <View style={styles.hcontainer}>
                                            <Image source={{uri:this.state.logoURL}}
                                                style={styles.iconImage}
                                            />                                    
                                            <View style={styles.vcontainer}>
                                                <Text style={styles.textH3}>{item.name}</Text>
                                                <Text style={styles.textP}>{item.description}</Text>
                                            </View>
                                        </View>
                                    );
                                }}
                                keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
                            />
                        );


                    }
                }
            </Connect>
```

What I aim is mainly to filter by item.name, refreshing the list while typing from a TextInput, probably going somewhere on the $filter variable...

Comment: One more thing, I wanted to sort it by name... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I've figured out the usage with the AWS AppSync Out-of-the-box queries...

```
query MyFoodList{
  listFood(
    filter: {
      name: {
        contains:"a"
      }
    }
  ) {
    items {
      id
      name
    }
  }
}
```

And it is finally working properly with this disposition on my react-native code:

```
        <Connect query={ this.state.filter!=="" ? 
                         graphqlOperation(queries.listFood, {
                            filter: {
                                name: {
                                    contains: this.state.filter
                                }
                            }
                         })
                         :
                         graphqlOperation(queries.listFood)

        }>
```

I still didn't manage to make the sort key work yet... will try a little more and open another topic for it if I didn't get anything...

Comment: Thanks, very helpful question/answer. I'm new on graphQL, and I saw this other question also about query with filter, and instead of `contains` it uses `eq`, but where does these query options come from? Amplify or GraphQL?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53947508/how-to-do-filteration-in-aws-amplify-graphql-client

Answer (score 0):

This is filter in use in React / Javascript:

```
const [findPage, setFindPage] = useState('') // setup

async function findpoints() {
  // find user & page if exists read record
  try {
    const todoData = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(listActivitys, {filter : {owner: {eq: props.user}, page: {eq: action}}}))
    const pageFound = todoData.data.listActivitys.items // get the data
    console.log('pageFound 1', pageFound)
    setFindPage(pageFound) // set to State
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

The async / wait approach means the code will try to operate, and move on to other areas of your code putting data into findPage through setFindPage when and if it finds data