# Perform a GraphQL/AppSync call from an Amplify js front-end - Error: Invalid AST Node

Tags: javascript, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I am trying to perform a listItem call with AppSync from my NextJS front-end. I can successfully make the following calls:

- listItems from front-end
- listItems with filter from the AppSync console.

When I try the call I get this error:

```
Error: Invalid AST Node: { query: "\n  query ListCards(\n    $filter: ModelCardFilterInput\n    $limit: Int\n    $nextToken: String\n  ) {\n    listCards(filter: $filter, limit: $limit, nextToken: $nextToken) {\n      items {\n        approvedTime\n        approvedUser\n        canRead\n        canUpdate\n        clientID\n        id\n        input\n        feedback\n        name\n        output\n        scheduledTime\n        status\n        type\n        createdAt\n        updatedAt\n        _version\n        _deleted\n        _lastChangedAt\n      }\n      nextToken\n      startedAt\n    }\n  }\n", filter: { cardID: [Object] } }.
```

My failing code:

```js
  const listCardsFilteredResponse = (await API.graphql(
    graphqlOperation({
      query: listCards,
      filter: { clientID: { eq: "d9a6c7a2-45b1-48a8-b012-5908d216f86f" } },
    })
  ))
```

My working js code:

```js
  const listCardsResponse = (await API.graphql(
    graphqlOperation(listCards)
  ))
```

My working query in the AppSync console:

```
query MyQuery {
  listCards(filter: {clientID: {eq: "d9a6c7a2-45b1-48a8-b012-5908d216f86f"}}) {
    nextToken
    startedAt
    items {
      id
      name
    }
  }
}
```

I've looked for [similar posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53947508/how-to-do-filteration-in-aws-amplify-graphql-client), but I still haven't had any luck.

Comment: did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by rewriting the code from:

```js
    graphqlOperation({
      query: listCards,
      filter: { clientID: { eq: "d9a6c7a2-45b1-48a8-b012-5908d216f86f" } },
    })
```

to:

```js
    graphqlOperation(listCards, {
      filter: { clientID: { eq: "d9a6c7a2-45b1-48a8-b012-5908d216f86f" } },
    })
```

Confusingly, this is in contradiction to the example in the documentation -
https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/graphqlapi/query-data/q/platform/js/#compound-filters :

```js
await API.graphql({ query: listProducts, variables: { filter: filter}}));
```